# Problems using Scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I already asked before about scrollview for being too slow and bugging

I knew the cause of that because I m using like 5 images on my layout and they make the scrolling too slow and freezing

Can you help me with that please . **Any solutions ?**

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   >
<LinearLayout
   ************android:(things)*****
    >

    <LinearLayout
        ************android:(things)*****>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_eml" />

        <EditText
           ************android:(things)***** />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
       ************android:(things)***** >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ttt_black_24dp" />

        <EditText
            ************android:(things)***** />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
       ************android:(things)***** >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dd" />

        <EditText
            ************android:(things)***** />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        ************android:(things)***** >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic" />

        <EditText
            ************android:(things)***** />
    </LinearLayout>




    <Button
        ************android:(things)*****
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any solutions to make scroll better with those 5 images  ?

Comment: I don't see where it can be laggy, how much images weigh?

Comment: when I remove ImageViews i scroll normaly without freezing

Comment: Probably the images are too big and it takes time to render images. Try to resize the images and try to avoid using `LinearLayout` as much as you can. They really require heavy operations and this takes time. You can also use the `Layout Inspector` to see, what makes it slower to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by ussing an auxiliar library to load the images, like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), it handles for you the device resources to load the image, the code will be the following:

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.image0).into(imageView0);
```

Comment: If you are going to use a library, go check either Glide (which is recommended by google) or fresco (which is currently maintained by Facebook). The latest picasso version is released in 2015, you can get the `Snapshots`, but glide and fresco are maintained more frequently, and they are better at memory management

Answer (score 1):

It can be because multiple reasons

```
1.- Maybe your phone is making it slower, did you tried it on other devices?
2.- Maybe the images are too big and you are shrinking them with just width and height in your layout
3.- Try decreasing the images size if they are big (i mean resolution and space)
```